# Using a global variable in different Lua script in different folder

Tags: lua, global-variables, scope, require

I have a a global variable defined in a file named `folder1/config.lua` as : `max_channel = 40` .

Now I would like to use this value in an anthors script in a different folder say: `folder2/script2.lua`  here is what I've tried:

```
local channel = require "folder1/config"
numberOfchannel = channel.max_channels
```

When I try to use `numberOfchannel` the compiler consider it as a string not a integer of value `40`. Why is this?

**UPDATE**: Here is how I try to use the `numberOfchannel`:

```
if num < numberOfchannel then  
...........
attempt to compare number with nil
```

knowing that `num` is a number and that the `if` statement works fine when I put for example `40`

and here is the begging of the file `folder1.config.lua`:

```
module(..., package.seeall)
max_channels = 40
```

**UPADTE**
After greatwolf suggestion  I tried to show the content the `channel` the local variable but I've got an error messagre saying :

```
    stdin:1: bad argument #1 to 'pairs' (table expected, got nil)
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'pairs'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

Comment: `when I try to use numberOfchannel` - how are you trying to use it?

Comment: What's your `folder1/config.lua` look like? If you're not using `module` then `max_channel = 40` sets the global `max_channels`.

Comment: Are you getting an error? What does `print(type(channel.max_channels))` say?

Comment: Can you show the full contents of the `channel` table after doing the `require`?

Comment: Your topic name is really misleading. You don't use global var in config.lua. After module() it declares var within module scope. Make sure that you required the proper file, print it contents as advices by greatwolf.

Comment: @greatwolf  how  can I do that ? is there a function for it

Comment: @Engine `for k, v in pairs(channel) do print(k, v) end`

Comment: Are you sure it's loading the file you think it's loading? It seems odd that there's no error on `require` suggesting it successfully loaded, but `channel` should at least be `true` rather than `nil`.

Comment: to be honest I'm not, but the problem that I have is that I have this mess code that I have to improve to get it work, and there is no comment no docs , in addition to that I'm new lua :\

Comment: Possibly folder1/config.lua does not return module itself. In this case your should use global variable to access the module: `require "folder1/config"; numberOfchannel = folder1.config.max_channels`

Answer (score 1):

`module` is deprecated.

In `config.lua`, just do:

```
return {
    max_channels = 40
}
```

Comment: I'll try that on the 5th of the next month but that for your help